# Cannot get ionic to build android apk

Tags: android, cordova, jvm, ionic-framework

I have problems getting ionic to build a proper android apk.

The ionic code is alright because I can build a proper apk on another PC.

When I run `ionic build android`, the android apk was successfully generated but when I install the apk, installation is not successful.

When I run `ionic build android` the second time, the following error was encountered;

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example,
>     an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>     chapter on the daemon at
>     http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read
>     the following process output to find out more:
>     ----------------------- Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Error: Could not create
>     the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred.
>     Program will exit.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> C:\Users\own\Dropbox\Workplace\xampp568\htdocs\ionicApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                       ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\own\Dropbox\Workplace\xampp568\htdocs\ionicApp\platforms\android\gradlew
>   cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\own\Dropbox\Wor
>   kplace\xampp568\htdocs\stkview\stkApp\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error, then I deleted .glade file and reopened the android studio.  It's working now.

Comment: May I ask where is the glade file?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar error before. What I did was delete `platforms\android\.gradle` and run `ionic build android` again.